# AWK Column Match in Two Files, Print Different Column

Tags: awk

The logic I'd like to write is as follows:

**From File 1, compare column 1 and also compare column 3 against any row in column 1 of File 2.  If a match is made, print the line from File 1, along with column 2's values (2) from File 2, as two new columns.**

When performing the match, only match the first 5 characters.

**File 1:  Node Links**

```
NODE1   eth1    NODE2   eth1
NODE1   eth2    NODE3   eth1
NODE2   eth2    NODE4   eth1
NODE3   eth2    NODE4   eth2
```

**File 2:  Node Loopbacks**

```
NODE1-USA   10.0.0.1/32
NODE2-USA   10.0.0.2/32
NODE3-USA   10.0.0.3/32
NODE4-USA   10.0.0.4/32
```

**Output File:**

```
NODE1   10.0.0.1/32 eth1    NODE2   10.0.0.2/32 eth1
NODE1   10.0.0.1/32 eth2    NODE3   10.0.0.3/32 eth1
NODE2   10.0.0.2/32 eth2    NODE4   10.0.0.4/32 eth1
NODE3   10.0.0.3/32 eth2    NODE4   10.0.0.4/32 eth2
```

Here's the basics of what I want but with an additional match.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}{print $0,a[$1]?a[$1]:"NA"}' file2 file1
```

Comment: Show some code that you tried or wait for someone to downvote your question and all the answers you may get.

Comment: There is no bash requested, everything in awk. Why is this tagged as bash then? It can be done in bash, but please edit your question to reflect this.

Comment: I've only performed basic column matching between two files.  I know how to compare two columns in two different files and print a value but I don't know how to do additional matching.  I've read that I need to use disk to store the first match and then perform the second action but I can't write it.  Edited post to include what I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[substr($1,1,5)]=$2; next} 
               {print $1,a[$1],$2,$3,a[$3],$4}' file2 file1

NODE1 10.0.0.1/32 eth1 NODE2 10.0.0.2/32 eth1
NODE1 10.0.0.1/32 eth2 NODE3 10.0.0.3/32 eth1
NODE2 10.0.0.2/32 eth2 NODE4 10.0.0.4/32 eth1
NODE3 10.0.0.3/32 eth2 NODE4 10.0.0.4/32 eth2
```

please note the order of the files

If there are unmatched entries you want to decode to "NA" instead of empty string, change `a[$1]` to `($1 in a)?a[$1]:"NA"`, similarly for `a[$3]`.